# Get current date of calendar and pass it to current fragment in infinitecycleviewpager

Tags: android, android-fragments, calendar, android-viewpager, infinite

i am developing an app like a diary with a fragment that contains an calendar an below this a viewpager. Im using two libraries for this:
1. horizontal calendar , Mulham-Raee
2. Devlight/InfiniteCycleViewPager
The viewpager can scroll endless in bothways (left and right side) this simulation is achieved using too many pages like +5000000.
I have already connect the calendar listener and the pager listener so that when the user scroll the page so the date tab does too and viceversa.
The thing is that i have a loader that load data from the sqlite db, and i want the fragment to load data that matches the corresponding date. See the following please
[app image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3oFS9.png)

First this is my page listener:

```
  @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {            

     //this method changes the current date in the calendar when the page 
      changes
       //this is done changing the value of the current day
                   update_calendar_position(position);

        //change the calendar day with the updated current_day   
                horizontalCalendar.selectDate(new Date(current_day),true);
                    mDateListener.getCurrentDate(current_day);



            }
```

Here i can get the position of the page but the adapter is using just 3 fragments for recycling. Now here is the adapter of the pager:

```
public class MyPagerAdapter extends SmartFragmentStatePagerAdapter {
private static int NUM_ITEMS = 3;

public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager){
    super(fragmentManager);

}

// Returns total number of pages
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return NUM_ITEMS;
}

// Returns the fragment to display for that page
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0: // Fragment # 0 - This will show FirstFragment
             {

            return FirstFragment.newInstance(0, "Page # 1", 0);
                }
        case 1: // Fragment # 0 - This will show FirstFragment different title
        {

            return FirstFragment.newInstance(1, "Page # 2", 1);
        }
        case 2: // Fragment # 1 - This will show SecondFragment
        {   
            return FirstFragment.newInstance(2, "Page # 3", 2);
        }
        default: {

            return null;
        }
    }
}

// Returns the page title for the top indicator
@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return "Page " + position;
}
```

}

I have tried getting the fragment from the position, but the position of the page in the onPageSelected method is 5000000,4999999,4999998 5000001, and so on. But the adapter position for the fragment is just 0, 1, 2 and the position of this fragments change without precision. This adapter extends this mechanisim from this:

```
public abstract class SmartFragmentStatePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
// Sparse array to keep track of registered fragments in memory
private SparseArray<Fragment> registeredFragments = new SparseArray<Fragment>();

public SmartFragmentStatePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
    super(fragmentManager);
}

// Register the fragment when the item is instantiated
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    Fragment fragment = (Fragment) super.instantiateItem(container, position);
    registeredFragments.put(position, fragment);

    return fragment;
}

// Unregister when the item is inactive
@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    registeredFragments.remove(position);

    super.destroyItem(container, position, object);
}

// Returns the fragment for the position (if instantiated)
public Fragment getRegisteredFragment(int position) {

    return registeredFragments.get(position);
}
```

}

In the class of the fragment inside the pager the loader needs the date to filter the right data. How can i achieve this?

```
 @Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {      


    return new CursorLoader(getContext(), MyContract.CONTENT_URI,
    null,"date=?",new String[]{Long.toString(current_day},null);

    //return a cursor with data of current date
}
```